# Delete a regularly recurring group of rows in a text file

Tags: ubuntu, awk, sed

Assume I have a large text file containing scientific data of the type

1.1 1 -105.122 
1.1 2 -114.091 
1.1 3 -99.913 
1.2 1 -103.564 
1.2 2 -108.001 
1.2 3 -102.402 
1.3 1 -104.875 
1.4 2 -108.223 
1.4 3 -100.291 
...

Let's call the first 3 rows group 1.1, the next 3 rows group 1.2, etc.

Assume this pattern repeats.

I'd like to parse through this file and delete every other group, such that the result contains groups 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, etc. and deletes 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, etc.

I've been looking through AWK commands (just getting started learning AWK), but can't seem to find a way to do this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it a typo that 1.3 has only one line and 1.4 starts with 2 instead of 1 in column 2?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is your friend :

```
awk -v FS="." '$2%2==1' file
```

**Sample Output**

```
1.1 1 -105.122
1.1 2 -114.091
1.1 3 -99.913
1.3 1 -104.875
```

**The dirty trick**

- Using `.` as delimiter you field 2 will contain strings such as `1 1 -105` & `2 1 -103`.
- When performing `$2%2` anything after the space is just neglected.
- Now, you want 1.1,1.3,1.5 and so. That means you're looking for odd numbers after the decimal. That is what we do with `$2%2==1`.
- Mind that the default action `awk` is printing the record. So if the condition is true, the record is just printed.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -ane 'if ($current ne $F[0]) {
                $should_print = ! $should_print;
                $current = $F[0];
            }
            print if $should_print;
           ' input
```

- `-n` process the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line into the `@F` array on whitespace, so `$F[0]` is the first column
- `$current` remembers the current group
- `$should_print` is true if we want to output the group

On each group change, `$should_print` toggles between true and false, and the current group is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a small awk script like this:

**script.awk**

```
$1 != old  { old = $1; grp++ };
grp % 2
```

awk -f script.awk yourfile

The script compares on each line the current `$1` with the `old` value. When there is a group change detected, `old` is changed and `grp` is incremented.

The second line detects if `grp` is even or odd. In the odd case the condition is true and the default action of printing the line kicks in.